# AngularJS, display text for boolean value

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML with AJS where I expect to see `Is Boss? : true`, when `person.IsBoss` has boolean `true`.

```
<span>Is Boss? :</span> <span> {{ person.IsBoss }}</span>
```

But it will be displayed as just

```
Is Boss? :
```

How to make AJS display "true" or "false" for boolean values?

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer. As long as the conditions you stated are correct, `true` will be displayed.  Check that the controller is loaded correctly and the person object is at the lowest level of the controller. Alternatively, inspect the angular scope with firebug in firefox to find where the value is populated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/se8ousa9/

Comment: @CD.. post that as an answer with a brief explanation.
sean717, It really is that simple.

Comment: Yeah..just double checked and the silly problem is that IsBoss is not the propery of person. @CD.. post your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code  should work just fine, have a look:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.person = {
    isBoss: true
  };
}
```

```html
<body ng-app>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span>Is Boss? :</span>  <span> {{ person.isBoss }}</span>

  </div>
</body>
```